# Question about the formula in combinatorics regarding ordered sets without repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, factorial

Currently I'm reading an awesome book: [Probability: For the Enthusiastic Beginner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XJSHWCX) written by David Morin (Harvard university). I highly recommend the book for anyone who like me is a beginner in the field and looks for a beginner friendly book about the subject. In chapter one, where the author discusses combinatorics, he presents how to build ordered sets where repetitions are not allowed, that is,

> How many different sets of $n$ objects can be chosen from a given set of
> $N$ objects, where the order matters and where repetitions are not
> allowed. we must of course have $n \leq N$, because we can’t use a given
> object more than once.

The author presented nicely via several examples and figures that the number of ways to build ordered sets of $n$ objects from $N$ objects $(n \leq N)$ is:

> $$_NP_n=N(N−1)(N−2)⋅⋅⋅(N−(n−1))$$

So until here, everything is fine and clear. But then the author says

> If we multiply this by $1$ in the form of $\frac{(N − n)!}{(N − n)!}$,
> we see that the number of ordered sets of $n$ objects chosen from $N$
> objects can be written in the concise form,
>
> $$_NP_n = \frac{N!}{(N−n)!}$$

In the above formula, in the fraction, I can understand why we have $(N − n)!$ in the denominator but I'm not sure that how the expression ended up as $N!$ in the numerator. It has been a while since I have worked with factorial expressions like this and I'm not sure to follow. Just as an example I tried with $N = 5$ and $n = 2$ just to see how the numerator of the fraction is equal to N! and it seems to me (please correct me if I'm wrong) that the author considers that

$$N! = N(N−1)(N−2)⋅⋅⋅(N−(n−1))\underbrace{(N−n)(N−(n+1))(N−(n+2))...(N−(N−3))(N−(N−2))(N−(N−1))}_\text{So is it correct to say that above expression = $(N-n)!$ ?}$$

And therefore

$$N! = \left(\prod_{k = 0}^{n - 1} (N - k)\right)(N - n)!$$

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. The original expression is the product of the numbers counting down from $N$ through $N-(n-1)$. The next number would be $N-n$, so by including $(N-n)!$ we continue the countdown all the way to $1$, yielding $N!$ altogether. E.g. $5\cdot4\cdot3=5!/2!$.

Comment: This observation is equivalent to noting that $N! = N\cdot (N-1)!$ which may very well be a key part of the definition of factorial depending on the author and repeating this an arbitrary number of times... $N\cdot (N-1)! = N\cdot (N-1)\cdot (N-2)! = N\cdot (N-1)\cdot (N-2)\cdot (N-3)!$ and so on...

Comment: As with many things in combinatorics, it is worth familiarizing yourself with alternate notations.  My favorite for this is $N\frac{n}{~}$ (*I typeset it as `N\frac{n}{~}`*).  The notation is very suggestive and aesthetically pleasing for things like the birthday problem: $\dfrac{365\frac{n}{~}}{365^n}$.  See more at wikipedia's page on [falling and rising factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Comment: @Karl Thank you very much for your time and your help!

Comment: @ JMoravitz Thank you very much for your explanation, it's clear now. Apparently a comment cannot be selected as the answer to the question on this forum. So if you wish you may write it as a reply so that I might choose as the solution for the thread. Thanks